# C++: Reading / getting data from a memory mapped file

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I have used CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile to map a file under Window using C++ VS2010.

The only way to get / read data from this mapped file that I know is to use MemCpy.
However, I was hoping that there might be a faster / more direct way.

Is there one? If yes, could somebody please post a sample?

Thank you!

Comment: Memcpy() requires a pointer to the view.  Just use that pointer directly.  This quacks like an XY question.  You could only ask this if you have trouble with arbitrating access to the view.  A named semaphore is required to prevent your app from accessing the view while the other process is updating it.  Life is a lot easier with a pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may cast the memory block to a data struct, as a pointer,

```
struct someStruct* data = (struct someStruct*)memAddress;
```

then 
you can access the data as a pointer

```
somefuction (data->var1, data->var2);
```

or

```
sum = data->var1 + data->var2;
```

you will have to be carful, and sure that the mapping struct matches the memory block, or you gonna get some junk

something like this

struct msgStructureCommon
{
    unsigned int messageID;
    unsigned int messageSize;
    char bufferLimit[1024-(2*sizeof(unsigned int))];
};

```
struct msgStructureID911
{
unsigned int messageID;
unsigned int messageSize;
//someData....
};

struct msgStructureID2013
{
    unsigned int messageID;
    unsigned int messageSize;
//someData....
};
```

// in main

```
char* buffer = receiveData(socket);
struct msgStructureCommon* msgRCV = (struct msgStructureCommon*)buffer;
std::cout<< msgRCV->messageID << std::endl;    
if(msgRCV->messageID == 911)
{
   struct msgStructureID911* msg911 = (struct msgStructureID911*)buffer;
   if(msg911->messageSize >= MSG_LIMIT_SIZE_911)
   {
      std::cout<< msg911->someData<< std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout<< "ops, message is not correct!" << std::endl;
   }
}
else if (msgRCV->messageID == 2013)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could perhaps also post a sample or edit your sample so that I can define the byte position and the size of the struct or so?

Comment: Yes, I mean just an example.

Comment: you can nest and mix multiple structures too